# Creation of counter in reference to section and subsection numbering

Tags: numbering, counters

How can I create a counter that when used under a section to count as follows

> 1.1
>
> 1.2
>
> 1.3

where the `1` is the section number and when used under a subsection to produce

> 1.1.1
>
> 1.1.2
>
> 1.1.3

where `1` is the section number and `1` is the subsection number?

The following is not a MWE. It doesn't compile, it is used to illustrate the use I am looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.1.1

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.2.1

\section{Section 2}

\Counter

% Should produce 2.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 2.1.1

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the counter, say, `acntr` to be in the reset list of `subsection` and make a query within `\theacntr` whether the current subsection counter value is `0` or otherwise.

If `0` use `\thesection.\arabic{acntr}`, otherwise use `\thesubsection.\arabic{acntr}`.

Since `\stepcounter{section}` or `\refstepcounter{section}` will also reset the `subsection` counter, the correct value is given at least with LaTeX kernels later than April 2015, otherwise the (outdated) `fixltx2e` package must be loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{acntr}[subsection]

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\theacntr}{\ifnum0=\c@subsection\thesection.\arabic{acntr}\else\thesubsection.\arabic{acntr}\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Counter}{%
  \refstepcounter{acntr}%
  \theacntr%
}  

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

1.1 $\to$ \Counter

% Should produce 1.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}

1.1.1 $\to$ \Counter

% Should produce 1.1.1

\subsection{Subsection 2}

1.2.1 $\to$ \Counter

% Should produce 1.2.1

\section{Section 2}


2.1 $\to$ \Counter
% Should produce 2.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}


2.1.1 $\to$ \Counter
% Should produce 2.1.1

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use ShareLaTeX and without the package fixltx2e it doesn't reset the automatically. I don't think that they use something outdated though...

Comment: I am sorry I deleted my first comment as it worked with the package fixltx2e.

Comment: @Adam: `ShareLaTeX` is ... well, I don't recommend it ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you very much though. :)

Comment: @Adam: [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) is using an outdated version of TeX Live (2014). [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com) is a little more up-to-date.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the info. Though I like ShareLaTeX more as it is opensource. :)

Comment: @Adam: Then you should love downloading and installing a stand-alone version of [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) on your computer. That way you'll have the most up-to-date content.

Comment: @Werner Usually I have a TeX version installed but recently due to formatting my pc and laziness I don't have one. :P

Answer (score 3):

The following is a little more verbose than Christian's answer, defining a macro that provides a way of conditioning whether you've called a `\section` or a `\subsection`, using the appropriate counter representation where needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\def\cursectioning{section}\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\def\cursectioning{subsection}\oldsubsection}

\newcounter{seccounter}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\theseccounter}{\csname the\cursectioning\endcsname.\arabic{seccounter}}

\newcommand{\Counter}{\stepcounter{seccounter}\theseccounter}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.1.1

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\Counter

% Should produce 1.2.1

\section{Section 2}

\Counter

% Should produce 2.1

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Counter

% Should produce 2.1.1

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 It is a nice answer. Also it is very informative. :)